# Express Render Template from String

Tags: node.js, express, dust.js

When a GET request is made on my site, I am trying to render templates that are stored on another server. Essentially my application will make a request to this server, and the response will contain the template that I would like to use. The server's response is a dust template in the form of a string.

What is the best way to render the template?

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   var options = {
   host: myHost,
   path: myPath,
   port: myPort};

   var templateReq = http.get(options, function(response) {
      var templateStr = '';

      response.on('data', function(chunk) {
         templateStr += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', function() {
         var dustParams = myDustParams;
         res.render(templateStr, dustParams); //THIS DOES NOT WORK
      });
   });
});
```

I understand that render looks in the 'views' folder to search for a template.

Also, I know that you can directly send HTML to the response using 'send', but by doing this I am unable to include the dust parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
res.send(templateStr);
```

Regarding having dust populate the params in the template, you have to compile and render it before using the `res.send`

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about Dust's ability to compile and render templates manually. I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an [npm module](https://github.com/john-doherty/express-render-template) to do this by extending the express framework to read a template url from the view model along with a css selector of where to inject the content of the view.

You call res.render as normal but pass template url and selector rather than layout

```
res.render('view-name', {
  template: 'https://courseof.life/johndoherty', // external url
  templateSelector: '#promo-banner'  // element within layout to inject view
});
```

It caches the template for 30 minutes before making another call to fetch the next version.